# How to get property of a class in Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a model :

```
public class Message
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string RegistrationCode { get; set; }
}
```

I want get its properties dynamically, in the previous version of `.Net` we do it by : `obj.GetType().GetProperties();` but in `.Net Core` we haven't `.GetProperties()`, How can i do it?

Comment: try `obj.GetType().GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties`

Comment: using System.Reflection; the written code is correct and no needs extra package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably missed to add the following using statement:

```
using System.Reflection;
```

I tried to run the following console application (I don't think that you will notice any difference in a asp.net core project):

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Message
    {
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string RegistrationCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var obj = new Message();
            var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

and I din't notice any issue. Below is the *project.json* for reference:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.1"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Are you sure that you use the latest .net core version?